# Proper class of Woodins and $\textsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$-hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

The $\textsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$-hypothesis is the statement that there is a $\lambda$ which is both a limit of Woodins and a limit of ${<}\lambda$-strongs. Are there any results relating the consistency of this statement to the consistency of a proper class of Woodins?

In [this paper](http://www.math.uci.edu/~mzeman/RESEARCH/ffs-0-120719.pdf) by Zeman he mentions that the $\textsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$-hypothesis *is* the existence of a proper class of Woodins and strongs. To me that just sounds strictly stronger than the above-stated version - but that's perhaps just a change in terminology over time?

Comment: Are you asking whether a proper class of Woodins and a propere class of strongs is stronger consistency-wise than a limit $\lambda$ of Woodins which is also a limit of $<\lambda$-strong cardinals? There is an easy argument showing this, which I can post, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm aware that it's stronger, but my question was whether or not it's strictly stronger or not. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: OK, I posted the argument, showing that it is strictly stronger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existence of a proper class of Woodin cardinals and a proper class of strong cardinals is strictly stronger in consistency strength over ZFC than the existence of a cardinal $\lambda$ that is a limit of Woodin cardinals and a limit of $<\lambda$-strong cardinals. The former implies the consistency of the latter and indeed the former implies that there are a proper class of such $\lambda$.

To see this, let $A$ be the class of Woodin cardinals and $B$ be the class of strong cardinals, and assume both of these are unbounded. Thus, both $A$ and $B$ have unboundedly many limit points. Since the limit points of an unbounded class are club and any two club classes intersect in a club, it follows that there are a proper class of $\lambda$ that are limits of Woodin cardinals and limits of strong cardinals. One can construct such a $\lambda$ explicitly as the limit of the following process: start with any Woodin cardinal, then take the first strong above it, the next Woodin above that, the next strong above that, and so on. Let $\lambda$ be the supremum of these choices. So $\lambda$ is a limit of Woodin Cardinals and strong cardinals, as large as desired.

Thus, the assumption of a proper class of Woodin cardinals and a proper class of strong cardinals implies the consistency of the existence of a $\lambda$ that is a limit of Woodin cardinals and $<\lambda$-strong cardinals, simply by chopping off at an inaccessible cardinal. So the consistency strength is strictly stronger.

Comment: Thanks Joel!
This got me thinking though. How do we actually prove that a proper class of such cardinals is strictly stronger than a single one?

Comment: By the incompleteness theorem. The former theory implies the consistency of the latter theory, since you can cut the universe at an innaccesible cardinal above $\lambda$ (and there are such cardinals, since there are Woodin cardinals above), and get a set model of ZFC + $\exists\lambda$ as desired. If theory $T$ proves $\text{Con}(S)$, then $T$ is strictly stronger than $S$ in consistency strength, since by the incompleteness theorem, $S$ does not prove $\text{Con}(S)$.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes perfect sense! Thanks again, and merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

I think I got a solution. If you find any mistakes or if anything is unclear, please let me know!

Firstly, recall that the $\Omega>0$-hypothesis (or sometimes stated as $\theta_0<\Theta$-hypothesis), is the statement that there is a $\lambda$ which is the limit of Woodins and there is a $\kappa<\lambda$ which is ${<}\lambda$-strong. So this hypothesis is weaker than the $\textsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$-hypothesis.

> **Proposition.** The $\Omega>0$-hypothesis is consistency-wise stronger than a proper class of Woodins.

**Proof.** Assume $\lambda$ is a limit of Woodins and let $\kappa<\lambda$ be ${<}\lambda$-strong. Let $\delta<\lambda$ be the least Woodin above $\kappa$ and pick some $\gamma\in(\delta,\lambda)$. Then as $\kappa$ in particular is $\gamma$-strong, fix an elementary embedding $j_0\colon V\to\mathcal M_0$ such that $V_\gamma\subseteq\mathcal M_0$, $\text{crit }j=\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)>\gamma$. In $\mathcal M_0$ we still have that $\delta$ is Woodin, as the extenders witnessing Woodinness lie in $V_\delta$ and $V_\delta\subseteq V_\gamma\subseteq\mathcal M$.

We can then continue. At every successor stage $\alpha+1$ we use the $j_{0\alpha}(\gamma)$-strongness of $j_{0\alpha}(\kappa)$ to get a $j_{0\alpha}(\gamma)$-strong embedding $j_{\alpha+1}\colon\mathcal M_\alpha\to\mathcal M_{\alpha+1}$ and again note that $j_{0\xi}(\delta)$ is still Woodin in $\mathcal M_{\alpha+1}$ for every $\xi\leq\alpha$. At limit stages we take direct limits, with the same conclusion. We now have two cases.

*Case 1.* There is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that for every $\xi\geq\alpha$, $j_{0\xi}(\lambda)=j_{0\alpha}(\lambda)$.

In this case, after we get to stage $\alpha$, we iterate $j_{0\alpha}(\lambda)$ more times, which moves the extender on $j_{0\alpha}(\kappa)$ up to $j_{0\alpha}(\lambda)$. Then $V_{j_\xi(\lambda)}\cap \mathcal M_{\xi+j_\xi(\lambda)}$ satisfies $\textsf{ZFC}$ and it thinks that there is proper class of Woodins (as $j_\xi(\lambda)$ is an inaccessible limit of Woodins inside $\mathcal M_{\xi+j_\xi(\lambda)}$).

*Case 2.* For every ordinal $\alpha$ there is some $\xi>\alpha$ such that $j_{0\alpha}(\lambda)<j_{0\xi}(\lambda)$.

In this case we iterate $\text{On}$-many times, iterating $\lambda$ out of the universe and leaving a proper class of Woodins behind (namely, all the images of $\delta$). **QED**

**EDIT:** This result coupled with Joel's answer then gives us the following string of implications: Infinitely many Woodins < A proper class of Woodins $\leq$ $(\Omega >0)$-hypothesis $\leq$ $\textsf{AD}_{\mathbb R}$-hypothesis < A proper class of Woodins and a proper class of strongs.